# Find the prime numbers in dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Output should be only prime numbers in list of values.

```py
data_input = {'number_1': [3,6,9], 'number_2': [4,10,11,21,23], 'number_3': [10,12,15]}
for x,y in data_input.items():
    for num in y:
        if num>1:
            for i in range(1,num):
                if(num%i)==0:
                    break
                else:
                    data_input.append(num)

data_input.update()
print(data_input)
```

This is wrong. The program is not showing any prime numbers, printing all numbers.

Comment: `num % i` when `i` is 1 ( the first value ) will always be 0...

Comment: Well, something is really wrong here. You are `append`ing to a dictionary (`data_input`), which --btw-- is the source (_intput_) of your data. You don't see a crash there because that line (`data_input.append(num)`) is never executed (apparently). The logics is wrong; try to `print` the values in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function and the [isprime](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=isprime#sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime) function from [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) like this:

```python
import sympy

data_input = {'number_1': [3,6,9], 'number_2': [4,10,11,21,23], 'number_3': [10,12,15]}
data = {k: list(filter(sympy.isprime, v)) for k, v in data_input.items()}

print(data)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv@Yq9NYFQTKOCBb9ESqmY4tImDclWKNJvj01BFPYwzBtmxy/0nJxOCa2fAkFcrF8Ye3TUtej8THCFd@FmezehVUUNNy3P8tJI@JpVNo9SHaRSstpO/0GdYUaVVKdm3Xtz41DDiJF4jyOZwPevJUYf0BoJLyGgnwIMmwR08FtTIhkbuVgZ27KOeEYipQ8)